# Oracle MAX(char(1)) union with null expands to 32767 bytes in record variable

Tags: oracle, plsql

Has anyone experienced this or know if this is a bug or a "feature"? My `CHAR(1)` value is being blown out with spaces to the maximum PL/SQL string length (32767) which of course breaks things downstream expecting only 1 character.

Simple test:

```
BEGIN
  FOR rec_data IN (SELECT MAX('Y') bind_all_ips
                     FROM dual
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT NULL bind_all_ips                        
                    FROM dual) 
  LOOP
     dbms_output.put_line('bind_all_ips length = '||LENGTH(rec_data.bind_all_ips));
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Output:

```
bind_all_ips length = 32767
```

The same happens with a table:

```
create table tab1 (bind_all_ips char(1));
insert into tab1 values ('Y');
commit;

BEGIN
  FOR rec_data IN (SELECT MAX(bind_all_ips) bind_all_ips
                     FROM tab1
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT NULL bind_all_ips                        
                    FROM dual) 
  LOOP
     dbms_output.put_line('bind_all_ips length = '||LENGTH(rec_data.bind_all_ips));
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Output:

```
bind_all_ips length = 32767
```

This only happens when:

1. The `CHAR` datatype is used,
2. It is selected and aggregated with `MAX()` or `MIN()`
3. That query is then `UNION`'d with another block that specifies a literal `NULL` for the same column
4. The results are fetched via implicit cursor in PL/SQL

It can of course be worked-around by explicitly casting it to `varchar2`, but this has to be a bug, right?

**Update:**

This behavior occurs on all versions including 8.1.7 (and possibly earlier), and from 9.2.0.6 to 12.1.0.2 it results in 4000 bytes.

Between 9.2.0.3 to 9.2.0.5, however it does not happen (it returns 1 byte).

Between 12.2.0.1 to 19.20 (and probably later, I can't test anything later), it results in 32767 bytes.

**Update Oct 27 2023**

Oracle Support verified that this is a bug and that it has been fixed somewhere between 21c and 23c .

Comment: Strange. I have 21cXE and the 1st PL/SQL block returns 2 rows (of course): 32767 and NULL when I ran it in SQL Plus. But, when ran in SQL Developer (ver. 21.4) connected to the same user in the same database, result was **1** and NULL.

Comment: @Littlefoot, That's interesting. I just ran a test against a huge number of databases of all versions and added an update. Interestingly the problem does not occur between 9.2.0.3 and 9.2.0.5, but does occur in all other versions. I was using sqlplus connected locally.

Comment: I think, operator MAX created new string variable, which is not related with field datatype. Maybe it has a sanse to use `CAST to CHAR(1)`, if this is so important: `SELECT CAST(MAX(bind_all_ips) to CHAR(1)) bind_all_ips`

Comment: An interesting thing is that conversion doesn't occur in plain SQL engine or dynamic cursor within PL/SQL. Only in native SQL in PL/SQL. And it doesn't bloat if you use some function on aggregated column: https://dbfiddle.uk/scOhC0KP. It seems at least strange and the issue is somwhere between PL/SQL type inheritance and SQL parsing.

Comment: Also interesting that the behaviour is different if you switch the union branches over. Which makes it look like a bug, not expected behaviour. And it happens with an explicit cursor too, which isn't surprising. [Another fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/43cBVZiz)

Comment: I created an SR, we'll see what Oracle says.

Answer (score 0):

You can get around it using `CAST(MAX('Y') AS CHAR(1))`

```sql
BEGIN
  FOR rec_data IN (
    SELECT CAST(MAX('Y') AS CHAR(1)) AS bind_all_ips
    FROM   dual
  UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL
    FROM   dual
  ) 
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line('bind_all_ips length = '||LENGTH(rec_data.bind_all_ips));
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

- [Oracle 11gR2 Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ODqcLGV2) (Length = 4000 before, 1 after using `CAST`)
- [Oracle 18 Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zwdtdNJ6) (Length = 32767 before, 1 after using `CAST`)
- [Oracle 21 Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5H9Ia4YC) (Length = 32767 before, 1 after using `CAST`)
- [Oracle 23 Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9rp3xN9E) (Length = 1 before, 1 after using `CAST`)

Comment: Yes, I know I can work around it easily. I'm just trying to determine whether it's  documented behavior or a bug. I created an SR, we'll see what comes of it.